# Is there a way in VHDL to make a series of components?

Tags: vhdl

Simply put, I have a component " X " and I want to connect 24 of them in a row; obviously means that the output of one is the input of the next one; I could just write them myself with copypaste and link them but I wonder if there is a way to do this elegantly.

I know the instruction `for I in N downto 0 generate`  but I don't think I can use it to create components in series, it only creates components in parallel, where each one works on a different value of the `I` parameter, or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generate statement is indeed what you need. Example if your `X` component has one input `a` and one output `b` of type `bit`:

```vhdl
entity bar is
end entity bar;

architecture rtl of bar is
  signal c: bit_vector(0 to 24);
  component x is
    port(
      a: in  bit;
      b: out bit
    );
  end component x;
begin
  u0: for i in 0 to 23 generate
    x0: x
    port map(
      a => c(i),
      b => c(i+1)
    );
  end generate u0;
end architecture rtl;
```

The input of the first `X` instance is `c(0)` and the output of the last one is `c(24)`.

Comment: good idea i see that you basically used `bit_vector` as a memory, didn't think of that. My X component works with std logic vectors instead of bits, i should make an array of vectors / a matrix to do this same thing i guess ?

Comment: @wattbatt Yes, absolutely, declare an array type if none exists already and use it to iteratively interconnect your components. Note that the `bit_vector` I used is not really a "_memory_". It would synthesize as plain wires, not memory elements.